# Trying to output what I want rather then the values it returns

Tags: sql, sqlite

Im trying to output Quantity <10 rather then output the values that are <10

for example my code is

```
SELECT job_id, po_id, 'Vendor ' || vendor_id as 'Reason'
FROM pos
WHERE vendor_id = 'SOS'
UNION
SELECT job_id, po_id, 'Quantity <10 ' || quantity as 'Reason'
FROM po_items
where quantity < 10
ORDER BY  job_id, po_id;
```

and its outputting

```
job_id      po_id       Reason
 ----------  ----------  --------------
002         AAA         Quantity <10 2
004         CCC         Quantity <10 4
004         CCC         Vendor SOS
005         EEE         Vendor SOS
006         GGG         Quantity <10 2
```

And this is what im trying to get. As you can see the only thing im missing from my code is the ability to output just the 'Quantity <10'

```
job_id      po_id       Reason
----------  ----------  -------------
002         AAA         Quantity < 10
004         CCC         Quantity < 10
004         CCC         Vendor SOS
005         EEE         Vendor SOS
006         GGG         Quantity < 10
```

Comment: How about to remove `|| quantity`?

Comment: I tried this but for some reason it wont accept it as correct

Comment: What do you mean? You got any error message?

Comment: No there is no error message it just says thats its not correct which is very strange, is there perhaps another way to fix it?

Comment: All good I fixed it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
SELECT job_id, po_id,
       'Vendor ' || vendor_id as Reason
FROM pos
WHERE vendor_id = 'SOS'
UNION ALL
SELECT job_id, po_id,
       'Quantity < 10' as Reason
FROM po_items
WHERE quantity < 10
ORDER BY  job_id, po_id;
```